# WebSphere MQ Queue creation

Tags: message-queue, ibm-mq

I have a queue `AIS.CICSUD1.BROKER.DATA` accessed by different process IDs such as BO01, BO02, BO03.

Can I create the same Queue for diferent process Id's? I tried it on WebSphere MQ Explorer but it's giving me duplicate Queue error.

My queue manager is on my local machine and I need to access the queues only from my local machine.

Please let me know

Comment: Is this MS MQ or IBM MQ?

Answer (score 2):

Queues must be unique on a given queue manager.  All of the different types of queue (QLocal, QRemote, QAlias, QModel) share the same namespace.  Typically in your situation some identifier would be added to the queue name.  In this case, adding the process ID seems to be the easiest approach.